# Are two approaches to kriging equivalent?

Tags: geostatistics, kriging

Is Ordinary Kriging the same as Universal Kriging in which the predicting variable X is constant and equal to 1?

The reason for my question is that in the source code of the gstat package, this seems to be assumed. No Lagrange multiplier is to be found in this code.

The piece of code to which I am referring is found here:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/krige0.R?view=markup&root=gstat

And in that code, starting from the line which has the following comment:

```
# ok/uk -- need to estimate beta:
```

edit: Lagrange, not Laplace, multiplier

Comment: What is a "Laplace multiplier"?  If perhaps you mean "Lagrange multiplier," then both OK and UK with a constant have to have a single Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Lagrange, thanks! I edited it. But UK doesn't need a Lagrange multiplier afaik.

Comment: If it doesn't have any Lagrange multipliers, it reduces to Simple Kriging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ordinary kriging is the same as universal kriging with only one constant covariable, equal to one.

Comment: Can you suggest any reference in which I can find a proof of this equivalence? Because whuber in his reply states that, when no Lagrange multipliers are applied, it reduces to Simple Kriging.

Comment: SK, OK, and UK are the first three [methods listed in a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging#Methods). The definitions it gives there make it clear that UK with one constant parameter is identical to OK. If you understand that there has to be one Lagrange multiplier per (unknown) parameter, the conclusions about the numbers of Lagrange multipliers follow immediately.